# Building VTK and Thread Building Blocks using Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, vtk, tbb

I'm failing to use TBB with VTK. VTK has an option to set which smp to use. When I set it to TBB Cmake can't find where my TBB is:

```
Looked for Threading Building Blocks in C:/Program Files/Intel/TBB;C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/TBB
CMake Error at CMake/FindTBB.cmake:272 (message):
  Could NOT find TBB library.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  Common/Core/CMakeLists.txt:42 (find_package)
```

My environment vars are:

```
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
APPDATA=C:\Users\geronimo\AppData\Roaming
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=GEROMIN-WIN8
ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
CPATH=C:\Program Files\Intel\TBB\tbb43_20150209oss\bin\..\include;
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\geronimo
INCLUDE=C:\Program Files\Intel\TBB\tbb43_20150209oss\bin\..\include;
LIB=C:\Program Files\Intel\TBB\tbb43_20150209oss\bin\..\lib\intel64\vc11;
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\geronimo\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\GEROMIN-WIN8
MIC_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=C:\Program Files\Intel\TBB\tbb43_20150209oss\bin\..\lib\mic;
MIC_LIBRARY_PATH=C:\Program Files\Intel\TBB\tbb43_20150209oss\bin\..\lib\mic;
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=8
OS=Windows_NT
Path=C:\Program Files\Intel\TBB\tbb43_20150209oss\bin\\intel64\vc11;C:\Borland\Delphi7\Bin;C:\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\Mercurial\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Users\geronimo\AppData\Roaming\npm
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=3a09
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
SCRIPT_NAME=tbbvars.bat
SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\Windows
TBBROOT=C:\Program Files\Intel\TBB\tbb43_20150209oss\bin\..
TBB_ARCH_PLATFORM=intel64\vc11
TBB_BIN_DIR=C:\Program Files\Intel\TBB\tbb43_20150209oss\bin\
TBB_TARGET_ARCH=intel64
TBB_TARGET_VS=vc11
TEMP=C:\Users\geronimo\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\geronimo\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN=geromin-win8
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=geromin-win8
USERNAME=geronimo
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\geronimo
VS110COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\
windir=C:\Windows
```

My tbb is in 'C:\Program Files\Intel\TBB\tbb43_20150209oss' and was downloaded from the Thread Building Blocks site. My SO is Windows 8.1 64 bits and my Visual Studio is 2012. I have tried to set a cmake var TBB_INSTALL_DIR pointing to the directory above but to no avail.

Any help on how to use tbb with vtk?

Comment: When this happens to me I look at the source code of the .cmake file that is supposed to find the package to determine why it can not find it.

Comment: Obviously, the environment points to the TBB location (`TBBROOT=C:\Program Files\Intel\TBB\tbb43_20150209oss\bin\`) but FindTBB.cmake does not take it into account but should - it's a bug.

Comment: I gave up. It's a bug it seems. Will try on Linux.